# Solr order by field not in document

Tags: sorting, solr, indexing, document

Just wondering if what I want to do is possible with Solr:

I have a Solr index of 'Users' [id, name, join_date] and on my site and I have a page /users which has a Solr query that lists all of the users in the index in alphabetical order.

On my site users can 'follow' other users. I have added another page /followers which first gets all the user_ids which are 'following' the logged in user from MySQL - then uses these IDs to query Solr to only return users which the current user is following.

This all works fine.

But the problem is, I'd like to be able to order the users returned on /followers in order of when they first started following the logged in user - I keep this information in a join table in MySQL. But my Solr documents don't contain this date - as obviously one user can have many followers and vise versa. Also I can't just use MySQL to server this page as I need to keep it Solr query-able.

Would love some insight into this - it's been bugging me for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that with [ExternalField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/ExternalFileField.html) but you need to export your info from the db to a text file (and keep it updated etc).

This guy [here](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/custom-sorting-in-solr-using-external.html) discusses a way to do it without ExternalField, but requires customizing Sorl code.